# Using statsmodels OLS on a test-set

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I would like to use a technique from Scikit Learn, namely the ShuffleSplit to benchmark my linear regression model with a sequence of randomized test and train sets. This is well established and works great for the LinearModel in Scikit Learn using:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
LM = LinearRegression()
train_score = LM.score(X[train_index], Y[train_index])
test_score = LM.score(X[test_index], Y[test_index])
```

The score one gets here is only the R² values and nothing more. Using the statsmodel OLS implementation for linear models gives a very rich set of scores among whcih are adjusted R² and AIC, BIC etc. However here on can only fit the model with the training data to get these scores. Is there a way to get them also for the test set?

so in my example:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import ShuffleSplit
from statsmodels.regression.linear_model import OLS

ss = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=40, train_size=0.15, random_state=42)
for train_index, test_index in ss.split(X):
    regr = OLS( Y.[train_index], X.[train_index]).fit()
    train_score_AIC = regr.aic
```

is there a way to add something like

```
    test_score_AIC = regr.test(Y.[test_index], X.[test_index]).aic
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of those measure are goodness of fit measures that are build into the model/results classes and only available for the training data or estimation sample.
Many of those measures are not well defined for out of sample, predictive accuracy measures, or I have never seen definitions that would fit that case.

Specifically, `loglike` is a method of the model and can only be evaluated at the attached training sample.

related issues:

https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/2572
https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/1282

It would be possible to partially work around the current limitations of statsmodels but none of those are currently supported and unit tested.